# Problem with finding frames by routing ID in Electron 5

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on a project in Electron where I will need to access user-loaded pages and perform some manipulations with their DOM.
I'm using BrowserView because apparently it's more performant and has fewer bugs, so my BrowserView init code looks like this:

```
let view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
        preload:  path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        nodeIntegration: false,
        contextIsolation: true,
        sandbox: true,
        enableRemoteModule: false,
        allowPopups: false
    }
})
win.setBrowserView(view)
```

Now, I need to inject a certain JS code into the main frame of the page, as well as the iframes.  In order to do that, I'm currently
using "did-frame-finish-load" listener in the main process, like so:

```
view.webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", function (e, isMainFrame, frameProcessId, frameRoutingId) {
    view.webContents.send("from_mainland", {"command": "inject_code", "frameRoutingId": frameRoutingId, "isMainFrame": isMainFrame})
});
```

This technique allowed me to receive "from_mainland" message in my preload.js file using IPC, find a frame by routing ID supplied in the call and
inject necessary code into relevant frame by calling executeJavaScript on it.

It works well in Electron 4.1.4.  However, yesterday I tried it on another machine that has Electron 5.0.1 installed, and everything broke.  Essentially,
function webFrame.findFrameByRoutingId returns null when I supply it the routing id from the call.  Any ideas on what's causing this issue and how to work around it?

Thank you!

UPDATE:  So, I was plying with it some more and discovered that in Electron 5.0.1 findFrameByRoutingId and firstChild calls will return frames only if they belong to the same domain, otherwise you get a null, so it looks like a bug in Electron 5.

Comment: Does the issue occur if you use sendToFrame instead of send? See https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendtoframeframeid-channel-arg1-arg2-

Comment: It still happens.  The issue I'm having is not that I can't communicate with frames as much as I'm unable to actually find them.  I'm loading a test page on domain A that has an embedded iframe from domain B (bbc.com).  Now, BBC has a bunch of iframes of its own embedded, and currently, as they all load I'm seeing a notification about that in my "did-frame-finish-listener" listener. So, in version 4 I was able to send an ipc message to my renderer process and use "webFrame.findFrameByRoutingId" to find the frame, but in 5 the same call returns "null"

Comment: is this helpful? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951#issuecomment-401579981